# Circuitpython take last variables from textfile

Tags: python

I am using Circuitpython for my microcontroller. I am posting datas from microcontroller to api. If there is no internet connection, I am saving datas to text file then sending datas when internet connected.

I am writing whatever my microcontroller do.
text file like this:

```
[{'name': 'exampleA', 
'time': '2022-03-15 14:11:55.145631',
 'id': '5456431', 
'howmany': 2, 
'character':None},
{'name': 'exampleA', 
'time': '2022-03-15 18:12:52.12541',
 'id': '5456431', 
'howmany': 5, 
'character':None}]
```

exampleA can repeat in this text file, I always need to check last exampleA's values because I need to do things at certain time. For example if I did something with exampleA at 14:00, I can't do things until 18:00. So, I need to find out last exampleA's time.

I need to read and write this file when internet is gone. If I have internet, I can take datas from api but when internet is gone, microcontroller have to do this by itself and when internet is connected, it needs to post this text.file to api.

```
string = exampleA  # it will be taken from user.
file = open("example.txt")
for line in reversed(file.readlines()):
    if string in line:
        print(string)
```

I think reversed is best way to get last value, but how can I take this string's `'time'`
with it ?

It might be easy question, if it is I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you control the way `.txt` file is created, I would change the formatting of it to JSON. With JSON you can easily load your `.txt` file into a list of dict, and then you can use standard list/dict voodoo to easily do what you want, without any custom data processsing.

```py
import json

with open("input.json") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)


for item in data:
    print(item["time"])


print(data[-1]) # last element
```

**input.json**

```json
[
    {
        "name": "exampleA",
        "time": "2022-03-15 14:11:55.145631",
        "id": "5456431",
        "howmany": 2,
        "character": null
    },
    {
        "name": "exampleA",
        "time": "2022-03-15 18:12:52.12541",
        "id": "5456431",
        "howmany": 5,
        "character": null
    }
]
```

**output**

```
2022-03-15 14:11:55.145631
2022-03-15 18:12:52.12541
{'name': 'exampleA', 'time': '2022-03-15 18:12:52.12541', 'id': '5456431', 'howmany': 5, 'character': None}
```